# Azure Runbook runs in Test Pane, not when scheduled

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, automation

We have created a runbook in Azure Automation which succeeds in the Test Pane but fails when scheduled. It is a PowerShell script

Included command timeout in stored procedure

Stored procedure is supposed to drop indexes, it would be expected that it succeeds when scheduled as well. We receive this error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior 
 to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
 At SQL_Agent_SprocJob:26 char:26
 + 
 + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check DTU scale up.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works

```
$SQLCommand.CommandTimeout=0
```

Sometimes this also happens when you have too low DTU, try scaling it up.